# Javascript/Nodejs Downloading audio file to disk

Tags: javascript, wav, createwritestream

Looking to download this wav file. Response.pipe(fileStrm) isn't doing it for me.
Ive looked around. Wondering what the standard way of downloading media from a URL to file is these days.

```
const request = require('request').defaults({rejectUnauthorized:false});
const url = "https://..../00015.wav";
const path ="./data/my.wav";

async function getVideo22(url,path){
    var options = { 
    'method': 'GET',
     'url': url,
     'headers': {
     }
   };
   var fileStrm = fs.createWriteStream(path);

   request(options, function (error, response) {
        if (error) throw new Error(error);
       //need to write file to disk
        
       response.pipe(fileStrm);
});

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Knew it was simple

```
 const path = "....";
 try {
       const url = "....";
       request(url)
       .pipe(fs.createWriteStream(path));

    } catch...
```